# Meteorjs equivalent of ws.send

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im trying to send a simple message that event has happened on the backend, specifically i have a observable that listens if anything changed/update in mongodb then updates the related record in elasticsearch.

Is there a Meteor equivalent of ws.send() on backend and use ws.on() on frontend?

How do i do that with Meteor?

I know of Meteor.publish/subscribe but its not quite the same and it does not fit my need

Comment: So what's the event you want to send to the frontend? Just that ES has been updated? In general pub/sub still seems right to me for this.

Comment: @obsidian my answer should solve your issue, if so, please accept it, otherwise please comment if it doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor only abstracts the Websocket away for you but it's still there. However, by doing to it also forces you to follow a certain pattern.

First, your need to track the connections on the Meteor-level, using `Meteor.onConnection`.

Then **you** need to get the correct socket instance for this connection which you want to send the message to:

**server**

```js
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.onConnection(connection => {
    const socket = Meteor.server.stream_server.open_sockets.find(s => s._meteorSession.id === connection.id)
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({
      msg: 'foo',
      custom: 'data'
    }))
  })
});
```

You can of course always send the message to all connected clients using `Meteor.server.stream_server.open_sockets` (array of instance-refs).

**client**

```js
Meteor.startup(() => {
  Meteor.connection._stream.on('message', (dataStr) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(dataStr)

    // this is your custom message
    if (data.msg === 'foo') {
      console.debug(data)
    }
  })
})
```

What#s left, and what is then up to you is to find the right client by connection that was requesting this message and at that point you might get back to pub/sub or customize pub/sub to run without a collection.

Comment: i did not test it but this seems it would probably work.

i created a new websocket server/client to connect and send events because i will need it either way for something else. 

Thanks for your time and answer!